# GParted - expand main Debian partition into freespace

Tags: debian, partition, gparted

I'm trying to expand my main linux partition from a Debian install, `/dev/sda1` into the 7gb unallocated free space. Normally I would just use the resize feature in GParted but because the free-space isn't alongside `/dev/sda1` I can't. How can I expand my main partition without corrupting the partitions/losing data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Back up your data.
2. Use a live USB system or similar and then from it:
3. Move the swap to the end of sda2.
4. Shrink sda2.
5. Enlarge sda1.

In fact there's no point in keeping the logical sda2 just for swap, so you might prefer to remove the swap and then sda2, and finally just build a new swap partition at the end and follow on with point 5.